# Android app doesn't show on Chrome OS google play

Tags: androidappsonchromeos

I just switched to dev channel on my Chrombook(ASUS flip). I got google play and was able to run apps directly but the chromebook didn't show me my own app. The app I wanted to run is an app targetted for tablet devices and in the manifest file, I have `android:normalScreens` and `android:smallScreens` set to false and `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"`. Could this be the reason why google play isn't showing me my app on Chromebook? What other reasons are possible? When I try to see the device from my desktop, it just says "This item is incompatible with your device". Thanks.

Comment: "Could this be the reason why google play isn't showing me my app on Chromebook?" -- those are not documented reasons. The smallest-width one might be an issue, though. "What other reasons are possible?" -- see [this page from the Chromium team](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/android-apps). I also have some notes in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/25/getting-ready-for-chromeos.html).

Comment: Yes, I've checked those pages and I don't have any other permissions set that could cause the app to be incompatible.